# Integral of the absolute difference between two cumulative distribution functions

Tags: probability, integration

Let $F,G : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ be two cumulative distribution functions, i.e., right continuous and non-decreasing. Remark 2.19 in Topics in Optimal transportation claims
$$
\int_{0}^1 |F^{-1}(t)-G^{-1}(t)|dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |F(x)-G(x)|dx.
$$
When $F(x)\geq G(x)$ for all $x$, I can show the equality by noting that
$$
\int_{0}^1 F^{-1}(t)dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x)dx = E[X],
$$
where $X \sim F$. Yet, in general, I have difficulty circumventing the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fubini's theorem is the way to formalise Alex K's idea.

$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\vert F(x)-G(x)\vert\,dx\\
=\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_0^11_{\{F(x)\wedge G(x)<t\le F(x)\vee G(x)\}}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
=\int_0^1\left(\int_{\mathbb R}1_{\{F(x)\wedge G(x)<t\le F(x)\vee G(x)\}}\,dx\right)\,dt.
$$

For all $t\in(0,1)$ and $x\in\mathbb R$, we have $F(x)\ge t\iff x\ge F^{-1}(t)$, or equivalently $F(x)<t\iff x<F^{-1}(t)$, and similar equivalences with $G$. We deduce that
$$
F(x)\wedge G(x)<t\le F(x)\vee G(x)\iff F^{-1}(t)\wedge G^{-1}(t)\le x<F^{-1}(t)\vee G^{-1}(t),
$$
hence
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\vert F(x)-G(x)\vert\,dx\\
=\int_0^1\left(\int_{\mathbb R}1_{\{F^{-1}(t)\wedge G^{-1}(t)\le x<F^{-1}(t)\vee G^{-1}(t)\}}\,dx\right)\,dt\\
=\int_0^1\vert F^{-1}(t)-G^{-1}(t)\vert\,dt.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this geometrically:

[image: crude drawing of area between curves]

The absolute area between those curves is what you're looking for.

You can integrate that either along the x or the y axis.

Unfortunately, I don't remember enough formalisms of integration to say how it extends to an infinite number of crossings between the two curves.